# Negativação de Respostas

Tags: debate

Não que seja o caso mas, uma resposta, mesmo depois de aceita (ou seja, ela solucionou o problema de que fez a pergunta) pode ser negativada?

Isso faz sentido? Em quais casos?

Eu acho muito estranho quando vejo uma pergunta marcada como aceita e esta (-1) ou coisa parecida.

Comment: Então, imagina que tu fazes uma pergunta, eu respondo a tua pergunta com um código que funciona e tu marcas a resposta como aceite. Mas não é a melhor forma de fazer por algum motivo...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sim, respostas podem ser sempre negativadas.

O fato da pessoa que perguntou aceitar uma resposta não significa muito mais que ela clicou lá no verdinho. Quase sempre ela acha que resolveu o problema dela, mas tem casos que nem, sabe porque clicou ali. Na maioria dos casos resolveu mesmo. Mas tem casos que não resolveu e a pessoa acha que resolveu. Tem casos que resolveu aquele problema específico, mas ainda está errado.

Essas marcações de aceitação e votos indica alguma coisa, mas não é uma garantia que aquilo foi bem avaliado. Costuma ser exceção, mas tem casos que as pessoas votam porque acham curioso, bonitinho coisas quem às vezes nem respondem mesmo o que foi perguntado. Outras vezes por concordar, mesmo que esteja errado e ela saiba disso. Tem casos que todo mundo tem certeza que está certo e não está. Um monte de gente achar que está certo ou é útil não quer dizer que seja de fato. Existem exceções.

Eu acho muito estranho uma resposta errada ser aceita. Mas em geral que perguntou não sabe avaliar bem. Em geral a comunidade avalia melhor. Eu nem ligo tanto pela aceitação, a não ser pelo fato que atrai votos depois :P

A comunidade também erra na votação, mas é bem raro, só ocorre quando o linha predominante de pensamento está errada, e isto ocorre na nossa área de exatas, mais do que deveria.

Votação e aceitação são coisas distintas.

[Um exemplo que levantaram esses dias](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123884/101). A resposta aceita funciona circunstancialmente, e tinha bem poucos votos, depois da aceitação passou ter vários votos. Nem sempre podemos confiar na aceitação e nos votos, principalmente porque as pessoas tendem a votar positivamente em coisas aceitas.

Answer (score 9):

> Isso faz sentido? Em quais casos?

Faz sim! As vezes essa resposta marcada como aceita, pode resolver seu problema no momento, mas talvez, digo talvez, pode vir acarretar um problema futuramente. Como por exemplo, ter um custo alto de processamento. Na maioria das vezes, quem negativou pode ser que aquela pessoa tem uma certa experiência, e sabe exatamente o que pode acontecer. Esse é apenas um caso dentre muitos. Não há impedimento nenhum em marcar qualquer resposta como aceita, isso é decisão de quem fez a pergunta.

Answer (score 6):

Não é estranho, é algo realmente esperado no sistema. Pode acontecer quando a pessoa que pergunta aceita uma má resposta por desconhecer o assunto. Pode ser também um sinal de que a pergunta foi mal elaborada.

Eu mesmo costumo tomar parte nisso. Existe um assunto que é recorrente no site, e que as vezes tem por resposta aceita uma gambiarra muito feia. A gambiarra até resolve o problema por um tempo, mas certamente um dia voltará para assombrar aqueles que a utilizam. Nesses casos eu deixo a resposta que considero ser mais correta e voto negativamente em todas as respostas que contém gambiarras. [Seguem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/200501/executar-javascript-apenas-quando-acessar-o-site-de-um-celular/) [três](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/194988/como-detectar-um-dispositivo-m%C3%B3vel-em-javascript/) [exemplos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131677/quero-saber-se-existe-alguma-forma-de-identificar-se-%C3%A9-pc-e-celular-e-exibir-um/).

Você não pode ver os votos negativos totais de cada post ainda, mas [quando tiver 1.000 pontos de reputação poderá vê-los](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user).